# Performance IEnumerable<T>.ToList().ForEach() over loop

Tags: c#, linq

Is there any performance difference between these two statements?

```
IEnumerable<T>.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

and

```
foreach (var obj in IEnumerable<T>)
   Console.WriteLine(obj)
```

Comment: You have a compiler and access to the `Stopwatch` class - why not test it yourself?

Comment: Yes, because you don't have to create a List<T> instance foreach over IEnumerable<T> should be quicker.

Comment: Arran, its not an duplicate because my object is a IEnumerable and I have to create a list first.

Comment: Not a duplicate, @Arran - different questions

Comment: Hence why it's a *possible* duplicate, if you don't agree, don't close it :)

Comment: Hence my confirmation that it is definitely not a duplicate :)

Comment: 'Confirmation' is not required, confirmation is merely don't vote to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first example, you will

1. Create a list by **enumerating the source**
2. **Enumerate through the new list** and call `Console.WriteLine` for each element.

In the second example, you will

1. **Enumerate through the source** and call `Console.WriteLine` for each element.

There are two performance penalities to the first over the second:

- The creation of the new `List` object
- The double enumeration: over the original source, and then the list